# Error while performing compound queries in firestore

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, nullpointerexception

I want to perform a compound query in firestore where I would like to get all documents with field `bloodgroup` equal to `A+` and with field `createdBy` not equal to `email`. This email is that of the logged in user. When I perform the query I get NullPointerException. How to perform the query correctly  `021-07-24 19:50:24.746 17550-17550/com.example.bloodbankcompany E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.bloodbankcompany, PID: 17550 java.lang.NullPointerExceptionatcom.example.bloodbankcompany.UserlistActivity$EventChangeListener3$1.onEvent(UserlistActivity.kt:217)` I am storing the document snapshot inside the `userArrayList` array. Without the `whereNotEqualTo` query I am getting output where my documents get listed in recyclerview.

```
private fun EventChangeListener2(){

        val sharedPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences("email", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val email: String? = sharedPreferences1.getString("email","null")?.trim()

        Toast.makeText(this, "ssrae$email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show()

        mFireStore.collection("applicationForm").whereNotEqualTo("createdBy",email).whereEqualTo("bloodgroup","A+").addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<QuerySnapshot>{
            override fun onEvent(value: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
                if (error!= null){
                    Log.e("firestore error", error.message.toString())
                }

                for(dc: DocumentChange in value?.documentChanges!!){
                    if (dc.type== DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){


                        userArrayList.add(dc.document.toObject(User1::class.java))
                        var number=userArrayList
                        var number1 =userArrayList

                    }
//                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,userArrayList.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

        })

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have edited a little bit of your code, if it still doesn't work add a comment.

Also, an explanation about changes is commented below.

```
private fun EventChangeListener2() {

        val sharedPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences("email", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val email: String? = sharedPreferences1.getString("email", "null")?.trim()

        Log.d("firestore email", email.toString())

        Toast.makeText(this, "ssrae$email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        // try and catch will avoid your app to crash.
        try {

            //ref
            var ref = mFireStore.collection("applicationForm")
                .whereEqualTo("bloodgroup", "A+")


            /**
             *  I believe since your email is of type nullable and there may be
             *  maybe a chance that email is null and is given to whereNotEqualTo
             *  I am just making an assumption here since I don't know what you
             *  recieve from sharedPreferences and whether it is null or not
             *
             *  So, what I have done here is,
             *  firstly, I have split the firestore call into 2 parts and
             *  Secondly, I have a null-check for email, if it is
             *  not-null ref will also include this query
             *
             */
            //null Check for email
            if (email != null) ref = ref.whereNotEqualTo("createdBy", email)

            // Snapshot Listener
            ref.addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {
                override fun onEvent(value: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
                    if (error != null) {
                        Log.e("firestore error", error.message.toString())
                    }

                    for (dc: DocumentChange in value?.documentChanges!!) {
                        if (dc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {


                            userArrayList.add(dc.document.toObject(User1::class.java))
                            var number = userArrayList
                            var number1 = userArrayList

                        }
//                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,userArrayList.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    }
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }

            })
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("firestore error", "Error", e)
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
According to firebase docs,

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#exemptions

If you attempt a compound query with a range clause that doesn't map to an existing index, you receive an error. The error message includes a direct link to create the missing index in the Firebase console.

Comment: Here I get output when I use queries `whereEqualTo` alone and `whereNotEqualTo` alone. But when I put the two queries together `.whereEqualTo.whereNotEqualTo` I get error.

Comment: can you replace your code with this one and send the logcat values before it fails.

Comment: so whats happening here, i.e., the code provided above in the answer is, if email is not null it will combine both ```whereEqualTo``` and ```whereNotEqualTo``` else only ```whereEqualTo``` will run

Comment: `2021-07-24 23:01:45.770 14803-14803/com.example.bloodbankcompany E/firestore error: FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/fir-2company/firestore/indexes?create_composite=
2021-07-24 23:01:45.771 14803-14803/com.example.bloodbankcompany E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:  PID: 14803
    java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: so there is a link generated in your error copy and paste it "https:// .......... 8QAQ"

Comment: @user16493824 Also, search for the tag "firebase email" in logcat... since I have added that in the code... does it print the email in the logcat? is the email null or actually email is being printed in logcat?